# ProgressDialog spinner not spinning in AsyncTask (On some devices)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This is my AsyncTask that is being executed when I click an item in a ListView.  I display a ProgressDialog while the task is running and dismiss it at the end of `onPostExecute()` as shown below.  This works and the spinner displays in my Nexus 5X emulator.  On any other emulator or my real device (Galaxy S7 Edge Nougat) however, the dialog shows but without a spinner or with the spinner but it instantly freezes.  I HAVE turned on all transitions/animations to 1x in the developer options by the way and all my other animations work so I know that is not the issue.

```
public class LoadHunt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private static final String TAG = LoadHunt.class.getSimpleName();
private PostLoginFragment listener;
private String hunt;
private int item;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public LoadHunt(PostLoginFragment listener, int item) {
    this.listener = listener;
    this.item = item;
}

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {

    pd = new ProgressDialog(listener.getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    //((PostLoginFragment)listener).getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... huntname) {

    try {
        hunt = huntname[0];
        String link = "https://cniekirk.com/gethunt3.php?huntname=" + huntname[0];

        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlCon.setDoInput(true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String s = "";

        while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(s);
        }

        in.close();

        return sb.toString();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection error!");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    List<String> resultSplit = Arrays.asList(result.substring(0, result.length() - 5).split(" xxxx"));

    List<List<String>> clueDetailsSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String clueStuff: resultSplit) {
        clueDetailsSplit.add(Arrays.asList(clueStuff.split("\\s+")));
    }

    final List<Clue> clues = new ArrayList<>();

    for(List<String> clueDetails : clueDetailsSplit) {

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 1; i <= clueDetails.size() - 5; i++) {
            if(stringBuilder.length() > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append(clueDetails.get(i));
        }

        final Clue clue;

        if(!(clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 1).equals("noimage"))) {

            clue = new Clue(clueDetails.get(0), stringBuilder.toString(), com.ploetz.dev.treasurehunt.Data.Status.LOCKED,
                    Double.parseDouble(clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 3)), Double.parseDouble(clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 2)),
                    getBitmapFromUrl("https://cniekirk.com/" + clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 1)));

        } else {

            clue = new Clue(clueDetails.get(0), stringBuilder.toString(), com.ploetz.dev.treasurehunt.Data.Status.LOCKED,
                    Double.parseDouble(clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 3)), Double.parseDouble(clueDetails.get(clueDetails.size() - 2)));

        }

        clues.add(clue);

    }

    //((PostLoginFragment)listener).getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

    GlobalResources.setHuntClues(clues);
    GlobalResources.setHuntname(hunt);
    GlobalResources.organiseClues();
    GlobalResources.setItemClicked(item);

    //System.gc();
    pd.dismiss();

    listener.onTaskCompleted();

}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(final String src) {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[1];

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            try {
                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                bmp[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            // Causes latch.await() to stop blocking and carry on execution
            latch.countDown();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Thread error!");
    }

    return bmp[0];
}
```

}

Comment: why the wait is not inside the thread is it working on UI Thread?

Comment: From a Fragment I do this: `new LoadHunt(PostLoginFragment.this, index).execute(hunt);`

Comment: latch.await(); doesnt seems to be inside background thread is working on UI Thread?

Comment: The await is outside so that execution only continues after `latch.countDown()` has been called.

Comment: It's weird because it works fine on the Nexus 5X emulator and it loads the images fine... Where should I put `latch.await()`?